How to fix expo-sqlite problem in react-native app
sto sviluppando un applicazione mobile con react-native e volevo creare un database per memorizzare alcuni dati  per non richiederli continuamente al server , ma sto avendo problemi .
these are the error messages:
ERROR  TypeError: 0, _expoSqlite.openDatabase is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes

 ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.

* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

I have a viewmodel that handles the data and I would like the database to interact with the viewmodel to give it the data it needs and this is my  StorageManager :
import { openDatabase }  from 'expo-sqlite';

class StorageManager {
  constructor() {
    this.db = openDatabase("mostriDB");
  }

   initializeDatabase() {
    this.db.transaction(tx, error => {
      tx.executeSql(
        `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
          uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
          picture TEXT,
          pversion INTEGER
        )`
      );
      error = (e) => {onerror(e)
        this.db.transaction(transaction,error);
      };
    });
  }

should create the database if it does not exist and the table if it has not been done before. Unfortunately when the app interacts with the storage it gives me problems

Hi Gianmarco, I had some problem with expo-sqlite and I solved using async await logic when I open the database and perform operations on it

sqlite have recently changed the "openDatabase" command to the following:
openDatabaseAsync()
openDatabaseSync()
